# Software Buttons Vertical while in Landscape Mode

Tags: android, landscape, back

If an activity is locked for landscape mode, how can i specify that i want the android software buttons (Home, Back and AltTab) to be in a vertical bar on the right ? (Like some video games have ?)

Thanks !

Comment: Is this not dependent on the device? On my Nexus 4, in landscape, the buttons always appear where you describe. On my Nexus 7, they always appear on the bottom of the display (that is to say, the navigation bar runs along the longer edge).

Comment: Interesting. I was assuming that was something we could change and not device dependent. At the moment i could only find how to hide them, but not specify their position.

Comment: On looking around a bit, it seems like this behaviour is controlled by the SystemUI application, which is (obviously) a system app, so changing the appearance of this would need a rooted device to begin with.